# Scriptural basis for importance of astrological predictions

Tags: astrology, astronomy

Hinduism had traditional lifestyle practice involving  faith and belief in entwined sciences of astrology  and astronomy.

Timing of marriage, muhurtham of Griha pravesam, starting of a new important activity are fixed after consultation by  competent astrologers.

What scriptural basis exists about validity and accuracy of  life / good events/ catastrophe  predictions based on birth time and time of planetary conjunctions  in general?  What are some most glaring demonstrated cases of occurrences based on pre-dicted and pre-announced calculations that came out true in the past?

EDIT: A motivation of the post is about what one ***can*** do today (versus what one ***cannot*** change.. birth star or subsequent planetary motions) to alleviate the malefic effects of certain stars/planets by resorting to Homam, Yagnam and other Pacifications. But alas it has to be undertaken in a diverted chat room, If at all ! .. I  was searching  for some fora that could stand up to guard some time tested traditions.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74401/discussion-on-question-by-narasimham-scriptural-basis-for-importance-of-astrolog).

Comment: There are too many questions in here, maybe you should try asking multiple questions instead of this one.

Comment: Thanks about suggestion. Hinduism the way it is understood and practiced is an integrated belief system at the core, or so I believe. The components cannot be dismembered to be individually dealt with. For example the single word **Dharma** has at least five English translations. So my request here, let it be confined to chat.